# Trying to Remove Individual gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl

I try to remove an existing individual from my RDF file, but I always get a NullPointerException. The Individual I am getting is there, because I can print out a property. Can someone please tell me what I have done wrong?

```
final static String SN = "http://vaceta.pavo.uberspace.de/RDF/social-media.owl#";

InputStream in = context.getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/resources/social-media.rdf");
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
model.read(in, null);
in.close();

Individual user01 = model.getIndividual(SN + "User01");
model.remove(user01, null, (RDFNode) null);
model.remove(null, null, user01);

output = new FileOutputStream(context.getRealPath("/")+"WEB-INF/resources/social-media.rdf");
model.writeAll(output, "RDF/XML", null);
output.close();
```

stacktrace:

[image]

Comment: Please add the stacktrace for the NPE to your question.

Comment: NullPointerException at which line ?

Comment: in this line:  model.remove(user01, null, (RDFNode) null);

Comment: You give 2 null references into a method and then you're suprised by an NPE? I think you should tell us why this should not lead to a NPE.

Comment: Sorry I am new in Jena and it is very confusing to me. I learned, that the 3 arguments are like triples, but what should I enter, if I want to delete the entire individual? thank you

Comment: @SirRotN In many of Jena's API methods, `null` is a used as wildcard in triples.  E.g., `listStatements( x, null, null )` provides all triples whose subject is `x`;  `remove( null, x, null )` would remove all triples whose predicate is `x`, and so on.

Comment: @vacetahanna You're on the right track.  Sir RotN's comment is not terrible Java advice in general, but Jena's API *does* use `null` as a wildcard in triple patterns, so your use is sensible.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Suprising. As far as I can see the only implementation I fond looks like graph.delete( Triple.create( s.asNode(), p.asNode(), o.asNode() ) ); it calls asNode() on all the parameters. Sure that the wildcard thinking applies here. (Code might be old just the first I found)

Comment: @SirRotN Yeah, the code here isn't right; I was just pointing out that it's not entirely mistaken.  I think what OP wants here is [`removeAll(s,p,o)`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using ModelCon.remove(s,p,o) which doesn't allow nulls.  You want to use Model.removeAll(s,p,o)  instead which does allow nulls and uses them as wildcards.  Here are the corresponding Javadocs (with emphasis added):

> #### [ModelCon.remove](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/ModelCon.html#remove%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode%29)
>
> ```
> Model remove(Resource s, Property p, RDFNode o)
> ```
>
> remove the statement (s, p, o) from this model and answer this model.
>   **None of s, p, o are permitted to be null: for wildcard removal, see
>   removeAll**.

> #### [Model.removeAll](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#removeAll%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode%29)
>
> `Model removeAll(Resource s, Property p, RDFNode r)`
>
> Remove all the statements **matching** (s, p, o) from this model.